# Help needed converting MySQL query to Doctrine Query

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

I'm trying to convert the following MySQL query which give me all clients who have not had an appointment for six months or more into a DQL query.

```
mysql> select appt.lastDate, clients.firstname, clients.lastname
-> from (select max(gapmtDate) as lastDate,gapmtClient from groomappointments group by gapmtClient) as appt ,clients
-> where date_sub(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)>lastDate
-> AND clients.clientid = appt.gapmtClient;
```

I've tried to match this with the following but I receive an error stating that there is an unknown column g__0 in the where clause. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong

```
public function noappointmentsforsixmonthsAction()
{



  $sixmonths=date('y-m-d',strtotime("-6 months"));

  $q=Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->select('MAX(g.gapmtDate) AS lastDate, c.firstname, c.lastname,g.gapmtClient')
 ->from('PetManager_Model_Groomappointments g')
 ->leftJoin('g.PetManager_Model_Clients c')
 ->where('lastDate <?',$sixmonths)
 ->groupBy('g.gapmtClient');

 .......

}
```

EDIT

Ok it seems the Doctrine site has been down all day I've tried editing the query to that below but it still won't work. Can any one give me the correct syntax.

```
$q=Doctrine_Query::create()
->select('a.lastDate, c.firstname, c.lastname')
->addSelect('(SELECT MAX(gapmtDate) AS lastDate, gapmtClient FROM PetManager_Model_Groomappointments GROUP BY gapmtClient) as a')
->from('PetManager_Model_Groomappointments a')
 ->leftJoin('a.PetManager_Model_Clients c')   
 ->where('a.gapmtClient=c.clientID')
 ->andWhere('lastDate >?',$sixmonths);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$q=Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->select('MAX(g.gapmtDate) AS lastDate, c.firstname, c.lastname, g.gapmtClient')
 ->from('PetManager_Model_Groomappointments g')
 ->leftJoin('g.PetManager_Model_Clients c')
 ->where('MAX(g.gapmtDate) < ?', $sixmonths)
 ->groupBy('g.gapmtClient');
```

I hope this works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply however MySQL does not allow the use of aggregate functions in the where clause.

Comment: @Graham Are you sure? I have used COUNT in a mysql WHERE clause before now.

Comment: I believe that this is correct from what I've read http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,193505,193505#msg-193505 http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/164529. It's most likely the format of my query. I had tried your format and I got an error regarding invalid use of aggregate function